# Install downloaded wifi driver--help?

Tags: networking, drivers, software-installation

I just installed 22.04 on a new build after having been away from Linux for several years.  I got a TP Link wifi adapter, and with a wired connection, Ubuntu isn't recognizing the device at all--it's not coming up in additional drivers.

I was able to download the driver from TP Link's site, but I don't know how to install it.  It's a zip full of a zillion files, and I am totally stumped as to converting all those files to an installed driver.

I can add whatever information would be helpful, but I don't know what that information is!

Edit:  The device is TP-Link Archer T9UH.  I downloaded the Linux specific driver.

Comment: I did download the Linux specific one here:  https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-t9uh/

Comment: The readme honestly made no sense to me.  I'll see if there's an installer.sh.

Comment: I had tried following the install guide, and it was a reminder that I need to brush up on Linux commands.  I wasn't able to make any headway.

Comment: try this one. That took some editing :P

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

The TP Link website only provided a zip file with instructions for Ubuntu 16.04. This might work on Ubuntu 22.04 but the gcc compiler will have a higher number. Don't mess with that one.

So this is likely a safer bet and does. Uses [rtl8814au](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au) and the commands are:

```
sudo apt install debhelper dpkg-dev dkms libelf-dev bc 
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -b --no-sign
sudo dpkg -i rtl8814au-dkms_5.8.5.1-24835.20190115_all.deb
```

Do click the link for a few other methods on installing  (including one for UEFI Secure Boot).